# Devices/Webcams menu item does not appear after installing virtualbox "Guest additions"

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I want to test some web application in MS Edge browser, which uses an integrated webcamera.

My dev machine is on Ubuntu 16.04, so I should configure a virtual environment with Win/Edge stack. 
I have created a virtual guest machine with Win10 (got it from  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/). To share my integrated webcam I installed a Virtualbox extention pack. But Devices/Webcams menu item does not appear in guest window menu after successful extension pack installation.

I have also installed a VirtualBox Guest Additions on Windows guest OS, reboot guest, but still have not Devices/Webcams menu item to make my host camera available for my guest Edge browser.

What should I do to share my camera for guest machine?

Host machine: HP Pavilion 15-au029ur,
Host OS: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit,
Virtualbox version: 5.1.10,
Virtualbox extention pack version: 5.1.10

Guest OS: Win10 64 bit,
VirtualBox Guest Additions version: 5.1.10

Also I tried to attach my webcam via VBoxManage command line tool as it described in official https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#webcam-passthrough
, but got such an error:

```
vito@VWNB:~/Downloads$ vboxmanage list webcams
Video Input Devices: 1
.1 "HP Wide Vision HD"
/dev/video0
vito@VWNB:~/Downloads$ VBoxManage controlvm "MSEdge - Win10_preview" webcam attach .1
VBoxManage: error: Attach emulated USB webcam (VERR_PDM_NO_USB_HUBS)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "WebcamAttach(path.raw(), settings.raw())" at line 1652 of file VBoxManageControlVM.cpp
vito@VWNB:~/Downloads$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable a USB controller for your VM. You can do this in the virtualbox UI by right-clicking on the VM, going to settings -> Ports -> USB, and checking "Enable USB Controller" with "USB 2.0" selected.

Comment: Indeed. It helps. Thanks Alex!